# Не работает jQuery + ReportViewer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Работаю на *ASP.NET 3.5*. генерирую многостраничный отчет с помощью *MS Reporting Service 2005*.

Нужно достучаться до элемента отчета (`td id="oReportCell"`) и задать ему ширину через *jQuery*.

Пробовал `$('#oReportCell').ready` и `$('#oReportCell').load`:

```
$('#oReportCell').ready(function () {
    $('#oReportCell').css("width", "100%");
});
```

Что делать?

Comment: 1. Покажите тот HTML, который вы пытаетесь распарсить. 
2. Вы уверены, что ваш скрипт исполняется после того, как $('#oReportCell') появилась в документе, а не до? Если ДО, то никакой .ready() не сработает.